# What would have happened if the sin of the spies never occurred?

Tags: messiah, moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies, ymoth-hamoshiach

If the spies had not given a bad report about Eretz Yisroel or the people had not accepted their bad report, how would history have been different?

I have heard speculation that upon entering the land, Moses would have been moshiach, he would have built the Temple immediately, and we would be living in yemos hamoshiach now. Is there a basis for this idea?

UPDATE: I found an example of this idea (with no source) in ArtScroll's Megillat Eichah commentary (pp. xx-xxi):

> The failure of that eloquent appeal was a turning point in Jewish history. Had the spies not fallen short, had Joshua and Caleb prevailed, had the people kept their faith in God and Moshe, then the evil potential of those forty days would have been forever destroyed. Israel, led by Moshe, would have entered its land, built the Holy Temple, and begun the reign of Messiah -- the ultimate redemption for which we still long.

Where might the author (Rabbi Nosson Scherman) have learned this idea?

Comment: Hu? Moses didn't enter the land because of the incident with the rock, not because of the spies. See: http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/537634/jewish/Why-Did-Moses-Hit-the-Rock.htm

Comment: @Ariel See [Devarim 1:37](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9965/jewish/Chapter-1.htm#v37) and Abarbanel [there](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14388&st=&pgnum=187)

Comment: [tag:revisionist-history]? I'm not sure why this sort of question is useful. What would have happened if X also hadn't occurred?

Comment: I consider it useful because it is not just a random scenario, but it seems to have been the ideal scenario at the time. It helps because it clarifies what was at stake in the decision to reject the land.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49291&st=&pgnum=60) Ohr Hachaim (see the very bottom of the page)? I didn't read the whole thing but it is speaking about if Moshe didn't hit the rock.

Comment: And if Adam and Eve hadn't eaten the fruit...? Lots of "what ifs"

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree that the question in the title seems like an irrelevant question. The question in the body of the post, though, seems legitimately on-topic.

Comment: @CashCow Yet a lot of these "what if" questions actually have answers in traditional Jewish literature. For example, if Moshe had not struck the rock, then he would have entered Eretz Yisrael, built the Beit Hamikdash, and Mashiach would have come.